# What is the difference in jQuery between returning deferred and deferred.promise()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm working in an ES5 environment using jQuery. I have some code as follows:

```js
var saveGame = function (gameState, saveStars) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  var starsSaved = saveStars ? false : true;

  model.game().saved(starsSaved);
  model.driveAccessInProgress(true);

  GW.manifest.saveGame(gameState).then(function () {
    model.driveAccessInProgress(false);
    deferred.resolve();
  });
  return deferred; // or deferred.promise()?
};

saveGame().then(/* more stuff */);
```

In this instance, whether I return `deferred.promise()` or just `deferred` the `.then` works as expected. Given this, I guess I'm a little unclear on what a promise is, and was wondering what the difference is between these two returns and when might it matter?

Comment: Does not answer you question, but it looks like `GW.manifest.saveGame(gameState)` already returns a Promise(like?)  object. If your code using `deferred.resolve();` would likely be considered as an anti pattern.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you mean that the function won't complete until GW.manifest.saveGame() resolves, therefore the addition of `$.Deferred()` is pointless and therefore bad? As the function must return something for the later `.then()`, what would I do for this?

Comment: If `GW.manifest.saveGame` already creates a Promise, then building a new one using `$.Deferred()` is an anti-pattern. `$.Deferred()` should only be used to convert something that is not promise-based into a promise-based version. Otherwise, you basically break the one promise chain and create a new one. ...

Answer (score 2):

You want to return deferred.promise() so that the calling code can't call resolve or reject or other Deferred-specific methods. That's not something the caller should have access to. It should only be able to consume the promise, not affect its state.
You can read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) as well .

Comment: I read that but didn't grasp what it meant at the time. Am I correct in thinking then that if I returned `deferred` that `saveGame().reject()` is valid, but if I returned `deferred.promise()` that it would not be?

Answer (score 1):

You would return `deferred.promise()`.

But it looks like `saveGame(gameState)` already returns a Promise so you shouldn't use `$.Deferred` here at all.

```
var saveGame = function (gameState, saveStars) {
  var starsSaved = saveStars ? false : true;

  model.game().saved(starsSaved);
  model.driveAccessInProgress(true);

  return GW.manifest.saveGame(gameState).then(function () {
    model.driveAccessInProgress(false);
  });
};

saveGame().then(/* more stuff */);
```

Having already a Promise and creating a new one using `$.Deferred` is an anti-pattern. the reason for this is that you might easily forget certain cases and your code might get stuck on such a point.

What if e.g. `GW.manifest.saveGame(gameState)` fails? You don't consider that case so you would need to add a `.catch`:

```
  GW.manifest.saveGame(gameState).then(function () {
    model.driveAccessInProgress(false);
    deferred.resolve();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    deferred.resolve(err);
  })
```

And there might be other cases as well.